# Diversos erros em código C - Como arrumar?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void rebeber_matriz (int l,int c)
{
    int M[l][c];
    for (l=0;l<4;l++)
    {
        for (c=0;c<4;c++)
        {
            printf ("Insira o valor do numero da linha: ",l," e da coluna: ",c);
            scanf ("%d",&M[l][c]);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{

    int l = 3;
    int c = 3;

    receber_matriz(l,c);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Teu `printf` tá incorreto. Dá uma olhada na documentação da função. Também, a função tá com nome errado - `rebeber_matriz`

Answer (score 4):

O código tem diversos erros, desde digitação, até lógica errada reaproveitando variáveis que devem ser separadas, passando por erro de sintaxe de chamada de função.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void receber_matriz(int l, int c) {
    int M[l][c];
    for (int linha = 0; linha < l ; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < c; coluna++) {
            printf("\nInsira o valor do numero da linha: %d e da coluna: %d", linha, coluna);
            scanf("%d", &M[linha][coluna]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int l = 3;
    int c = 3;
    receber_matriz(l, c);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pv4OZJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ckeiuftr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/FillMatrix.c).

Se está recebendo o tamanho da matriz por parâmetros, é ele que deve ser usado e não uma valor fixo. Pior ainda ser 4 no exemplo, já que a matriz está sendo criado com 3 elementos. Obviamente o parâmetro não pode ser manipulado, sobe pena de perder seu valor. Tem que criar uma variável auxiliar para fazer o incremento em cada passo.

O [`printf()` tem uma sintaxe própria](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) para passar argumentos para a *string* a ser impressa.

Comment: Salva pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void receber_matriz(l, c) {
    int M[l][c];
    for (l = 0; l < 4 ; l++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            printf("\nInsira o valor do numero da linha: %d e da coluna: %d", l, c);
            scanf("%d", &M[l][c]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int l = 0;
    int c = 0;

   receber_matriz(l, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Não é necessário a biblioteca matemática, já que é uma simples entrada.

Entendo que pode-se usar a mesma variável de entrada da função para ler do teclado na matriz.

As variáveis podem ser inicializadas com 0, já que entrarão no for do mesmo jeito. Inicializadas com 0 seria a questão de lógica porque programar não é só escrever código. Poderia até ter valores negativos, mas não seria ideal.

Poderia até usar while para as duas. Seria menor linha de código, mas tem o detalhe de: o for é quando se conhece o fim; o while é para casos de repetição não contáveis ou fim desconhecido.

Comment: Quem usa `l` como variável (sugestão: `linha`, `lin`, ou `li`) está a brincar com o destino :-)

Comment: @pmg os professores começam ensinaod assim. Não sei porque, mas não faz sentido. Acho que pode estimular a pensar nome de variáveis, métodos, etc já no inicio da aprendisagem.